# Measurable Homomorphism between $\Bbb R$ and Lie Groups

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lie-groups

Let φ : $f:\Bbb R \to G $ be a **measurable homomorphism**, where $G$ is a Lie Group with a choice of Haar measure.

How can I prove that $\varphi$ is continuous?

When $ G=\Bbb R$ is well known that $\varphi$ is a linear function.

I also read that in general, when $G$ is locally compact, the result is also true (even in Polish Spaces, but in that case we change measurable by semi-measurable)

Help is appreciated.